# Independence of variables in expectation

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, independence, indicator-function

I know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and have an expression $$E[I(Y>X)*I(X>2)].$$

Is the independence between $X$ and $Y$ enough to say that $$E[I(Y>X)*I(X>2)] = E[I(Y>X)]*E[I(X>2)]?$$

This does not seem too difficult, yet I am having trouble justifying or disproving the equality.

$I()$ is the standard indicator function.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $I(\cdot)$?

Comment: Just clarified in the question, thanks @mhdadk

Comment: Let each of the ordered pairs $(1,0),$ $(1,2),$ $(3,0),$ $(3,2)$ have probability $1/4$ and suppose $X$ is the first component and $Y$ is the second component.  You can verify (easily) that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $E[I(Y\gt X)]=1/4,$ $E[I(X\gt 2)]=1/2.$  However, the event $Y\gt X \gt 2$ is empty, whence it has zero probability: the equation doesn't work out. I found this counterexample by drawing graphs of these events in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @mhdadk Indicator function. `I(Y > X)` is 1 iff Y > X, and 0 if otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not enough. Although $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the events $\{X<Y\}$ and $\{X>2\}$ are not. Let's say $Y$ is a constant random variable and is equal to $2$ with probability $1$. Then, $$E[I(X<2)I(X>2)]=0$$

But, $E[I(X<2)]E[I(X>2)]$ depends on $X$.